# Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. - In Flutter/Dart

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart

I was trying to build an app that takes in the Title, Date, Link, Priority level and then displays them using Flutter and SQLite.
I originally built it without 'link' and it was working perfectly, but when I added the filed 'link' it gives me this error:

```
 E/flutter ( 8491): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(table task_table has no column named link (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO task_table (title, date, link, priority, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
E/flutter ( 8491): #################################################################
E/flutter ( 8491): Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
E/flutter ( 8491): Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
E/flutter ( 8491):  (table task_table has no column named link (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO task_table (title, date, link, priority, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?))
E/flutter ( 8491): #################################################################) sql 'INSERT INTO task_table (title, date, link, priority, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' args [math, 2021-04-28T00:00:00.000, google, Medium, 0]}
```

The code associated with this is distributed in two files: a database helper file that basically stores all the functions for database management

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:todo/models/task_model.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._instance();
  static Database _db;

  DatabaseHelper._instance();

  String taskTable = 'task_table';
  String colId = 'id';
  String colTitle = 'title';
  String colDate = 'date';
  String colLink = 'link';
  String colPriority = 'priority';
  String colStatus = 'status';

  // task tables
  // Id | Title | Date | Link | Priority | Status
  //  0     ''     ''     ''        ''
  //  2     ''     ''     ''        ''
  //  3     ''     ''     ''        ''

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = await _initDb();
    }
    return _db;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDb() async {
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = dir.path + 'todo_list.db';
    final todoListDb =
        await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
    return todoListDb;
  }

  void _createDb(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $taskTable($colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $colTitle TEXT, $colDate TEXT, $colLink TEXT, $colPriority TEXT, $colStatus INTEGER)');
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getTaskMapList() async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await db.query(taskTable);
    return result;
  }

  Future<List<Task>> getTaskList() async {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> taskMapList = await getTaskMapList();
    final List<Task> taskList = [];
    taskMapList.forEach((taskMap) {
      taskList.add(Task.fromMap(taskMap));
    });
    taskList.sort((taskA, taskB) => taskA.date.compareTo(taskB.date));
    return taskList;
  }

  Future<int> insertTask(Task task) async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    final int result = await db.insert(taskTable, task.toMap());
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> updateTask(Task task) async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    final int result = await db.update(taskTable, task.toMap(),
        where: '$colId = ?', whereArgs: [task.id]);
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> deleteTask(int id) async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    final int result =
        await db.delete(taskTable, where: '$colId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
    return result;
  }
}
```

And the second file is a database model file, which contains the database creation etc. :

```
class Task {
  int id;
  String title;
  DateTime date;
  String link;
  String priority;
  int status; // 0 - complete, 1- complete

  Task({
    this.title,
    this.date,
    this.link,
    this.priority,
    this.status,
  });
  Task.withId({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.date,
    this.link,
    this.priority,
    this.status,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (id != null) {
      map['id'] = id;
    }
    map['title'] = title;
    map['date'] = date.toIso8601String();
    map['link'] = link;
    map['priority'] = priority;
    map['status'] = status;
    return map;
  }

  factory Task.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Task.withId(
        id: map['id'],
        title: map['title'],
        date: DateTime.parse(map['date']),
        link: map['link'],
        priority: map['priority'],
        status: map['status']);
  }
}
```

This is my first time working with databases in flutter so any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that you don't have the column available in the table. The problem is that the db is not created every time you start the app. There are two solutions to your problem here:

1. For debug purposes, just delete the app and re-run the code, this will regenerate the database with the correct columns. WARNING: this is just for debug only, not for production.
2. For production, when you add changes on database, you have to increase the database version, in your case from 1 to let's say 2. Next, the `openDatabase` method has a parameter `onUpgrade` that will be called when the database version is upgraded, in your case from 1 to 2, here you'll have to run additional sql commands to update your table. Something like this:

```
await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb, onUpgrade: (db, old, newVersion) async {
      if(old < 2) {
          await db.execute("ALTER TABLE task_table ADD link TEXT");
      }
});
```

Also do not forget to update your create table statement to add your new column there.

One scenario would be that you don't want to save the `link` in the db, in this case you'll have to remove it from json serialization (your `toMap` method) .